# When to use “have” vs. ”get”

Tags: word-choice, grammar

For example -

> I got $300
>      I have $300

Which is more correct? Please advice proper use of these terms. Thank you.

Comment: I believe this would have been a better question for [ell.SE].

Comment: Such use of "got" belongs to pidgin grammar. You would not use it that way in formal writing. Not in technical/business journals/manuals. I am not enthusiastic about such pidgin grammar.  I am not an expert in pidgin grammar, either.

Comment: @J.R. While the question seems basic and many native speakers intuitively choose correctly, I think the reasons are somewhat subtle and warrant a discussion here.

Comment: @bib - I suppose the question could be asked at either place, but, I have to wonder: The answer you've provided, would it be of more interest to the serious etymologist? Or to the English learner? Moreover, don't miss the larger purpose for my comment, which was not necessary tied to this question (migration is such a chore), but at others down the road. I would think any "curious soul" who writes "Please advice proper use" would be glad to learn of another site devoted to enthusiastic English learners, particularly when that user has only been on the Stack Exchange for a few hours.

Comment: @J.R. I agree that the other site is a boon to non-native speakers. I agree that this question is possibly borderline. I think that we should keep questions that may be of interest to either site and perhaps cross list them. I think there are many questions on our site that are of interest to others than serious etymologists (and this is really not an etymology question, but rather one of grammatical usage). I don't consider myself a serious etymologist, but rather an enthusiastic journeyman. The complexity of *get* is one that challenges many, not just learners.

Comment: @bib - Fair enough. I'm no etymologist, either. While attempting to explain why I left my original comment, I was just using "serious etymologist" as a euphemism for "typical ELU user" (most of whom probably already "get" the difference between _get_ and _have_, even if it is interesting to think about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Get](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/got)* has several meanings and usages, and the construction depends on which you are seeking. What follows is a discussion of US English only.

In the first sentence you offer, it appears to be used in the past tense (*got*), transitively meaning

> to come into possession of; receive or earn

*Get* (and *got*) in this usage suggest an activity such as taking possession.

Your first example would work in the following context

> *Did you get cash from the ATM machine?*
>
> *I got $300*.

The second sentence would make more sense when there is no action involved, but rather statement of condition

> *Do you have any money?*
>
> *I have $300.*

As offered by Barrie English, this latter sense is sometimes expressed as

> *I've got $300*

This is almost always used in the contracted form and would probably only be used in informal speech rather than in writing. Unless you were trying to rebut a negation, you would rarely find

> *I have got $300.*

If you were trying to use the present perfect or past perfect tense to indicate taking possession earlier, a different participle would be used

> *I have often gotten $300 from that cash machine.*

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of saying it in British English is ‘I’ve got $300.’ American English, I believe, prefers ‘I have $300.’ ‘I got $300' is nonstandard in both, when it refers to the amount of money in the speaker's possession at the time of speaking.

Comment: my query is not only money specific. i got an ipod , i have an ipod . which is correct ?

Comment: The same applies.

Comment: I have got an iPod

Comment: Which is correct? Neither one; you need to capitalize "I" to make those correct. Moreover, it's not always one or the other; you need to set the context: "What did you get at the store?" _I got an iPod at the store._ "What do you have in your pocket?" _I have an iPod in my pocket._

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that 'get' implies an action where you usually had to look or ask or do something for the object in question. And 'have' implies that you already have possession of such object. 
'Go get your notebook' 
Whereas 'go have your notebook' would be incorrect. (I think)

Answer (score -2):

there is not a slight difference b/w the sentences you are talking of. the sentence " i got an iPod" means the iPod has recently come in your possession from any source. the second one -" i have an iPod" indicate that you did not get it instantly. actually you are telling someone about the fact that the i pod is in your possession.